# Convert polynomials and fractions in a finit field?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

I am trying to understand how finite field works, and I am stuck on converting high power polynomials into a power of the field, also converting fractions into integers.

1. $8^{-1}\cdot44$ in $\Bbb F_{101}$ (the answer is 56 mod 101) I am not too sure how it got there
2. $x^4$ in $\Bbb F_{\large 2^3}$

any enlightenment would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you understand what $8^{-1}$ is?

Comment: yes it's essentially $44/8$ correct?

Comment: Only if you understand what $44/8$ is.

Comment: as far as I know it's a simple fraction? $\frac{44}8$ which yields 5.5?

Comment: Polynomials over finite fields work exactly the way they normally do; that is, just because
$$a^p=a$$
for any $a\in\mathbb{F}_p$ **does not** mean that the polynomials $x^p$ and $x$ are equal as elements of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Thus, in your second question, there is nothing to do.

Comment: @Yonk $8^{-1}$ is just shorthand notation for the only element $x$ of your field such that $8x=1$.

Comment: @GitGud That explains why it didn't make any sense to me. so does how would I intepret it? $8 = 44mod101$?

Comment: @ZevChonoles I guess I should rephrase my questions, I want to know that if I have to reduce the $a^p$ into a, what is the process to do so?

Comment: @Yonk: There is no process... or rather, the "process" is "throw away the exponent of $p$". There's nothing to it. For example, let $p=17$, and let $a$ be the number $5$, considered as an element of $\mathbb{F}_{17}$. Then
$$5^{17}=5,$$
as elements of $\mathbb{F}_{17}$, or in other words,
$$5^{17}\equiv 5\bmod 17.$$

Comment: @Yonk You don't know what $8^{-1}\cdot 44$ is and you want to find what it is. Call it $a$. So $8^{-1}\cdot 44\equiv a \pmod {101}$. Multiply by $8$ on both sides to get something equivalent which you should be able to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have seen answers for the first question. For the second question:

The answer won't be unique. To construct a field of order $p^n$ for a prime $p$ you consider the polynomial ring $F_p[x]$ and a monic ireducible polynomial $f$ of degree $n$. Here $p=2$ and $n=3$.

Note that a polynomial of degree $3$ is reducible if and only if it has a zero. Hence we want a monic polynomial of degree $3$ in $F_2[x]$ with no zeros.
It will be of the form

$$f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$$

where $a,b,c\in F_2$. Now $0$ shan't be a zero, so $c=1$. Then $1$ shan't be a zero as well so $(a,b)=(1,0)$ or $(a,b)=(0,1)$.

We end up with two options

$$f(x)=x^3+x^2+1$$ or $$g(x)=x^3+x+1$$.

In $F_2[x]/f$ we have $x^4=x\cdot x^3=x(x^2+1)=x^3+x=x^2+x+1$.

In $F_2[x]/g$ we have $x^4=x\cdot x^3=x(x+1)=x^2+x$.

You see that the answer is not unique.

Comment: precisely what I was looking for, much appreciated!

Comment: @YonkShi: You might have gotten helpful answers sooner, if you had asked for this. Normally people denote by $x$ a variable, an indeterminate. You, OTOH, used it as a specific element of the finite field of 8 elements, i.e. a constant (=coset of $x$). Mind you, newcomers to the area often make this mistake, so don't worry. But you  would benefit learning about quotient rings before you tackle finite fields.

Answer (score 2):

$8^{-1}\cdot 44 = 2^{-1}\cdot 4^{-1}\cdot 4\cdot 11=2^{-1}\cdot 11 $. Noting that $2\cdot 51=1$, we see that this is $51\cdot 11=561=56$.

As polynomial $x^4\in F_8[X]$ is just that - $x^4$.
However, interpreted as $function$ from $F_8$ to itself, the answer may differ / the expression be rewritten. Is it the latter you are spposed to do?

Comment: I'm afraid that "-" before that $\,x^4\,$ may induce the OP to believe that's a minus sign...perhaps ":" would be better?

Comment: Does the OP really mean $x^4\in F_8[x]$ or rather $x^4\in F_8\cong F_2[x]/f(x)$? Then $x^4$ would be equivalent to sth of a lower degree. It won't be unique, but maybe there is some convention (s)he isn't telling us about.

Comment: @Yonk Shi, maybe you want to comment on that.

Comment: @SimonMarkett Sorry I just saw your message. Yes, I think Hagen mistunderstood me. $F_{2^3}$ means a field $F_{2}$ but with a maximum degree of 3 in that field. Thus $x^4$ is out of that bound, it needs to be mapped down to something like $x^2+x$